# Is there a special etiquette in mixed doubles tennis?

Tags: tennis

Though mixed doubles are rarely broadcasted on Television, they are a part of official Tennis tournaments, including the Grand Slams. I am wondering, whether on that professional level, there is any unwritten Rules between the players.

Female players at average and at top-level have slower hitting speeds, which is especially important regarding serves. So even if they do not have slower reaction times, a women will simply not be used to returning a 220 kph serve (unless she is specializing on mixed doubles). So would a male server "restrain" himself when serving? Likewise, would a male player "attack" the female opponent standing at the net like he would with a male counterpart?

Comment: What do you mean by male and female?

Comment: Tennis maintains the traditional binary-sex-assignment grouping of players into male and female groups. Mixed doubles means exactly having one male and one female player together. The words have no meaning beyond their standard English definitions.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no special etiquette in mixed doubles tennis matches at the professional level. Professional players are expected to adhere to the rules of the game, that is all. As professionals, they are aware of their own strenghts and weaknesses and also of their opponents. If the opposing mixed double team has a female player who has difficulty returning a hard service, that is simply a bonus. No restaint is required or expected, as this would only harm the chances of the restraining team. Similarly if the male of the opposing team has a poor backhand, it is perfectly okay to direct as many balls as possible to his backhand. If a team loses matches as a result of these weaknesses, the two players should address this problem and train harder. That is what professionals do.

Comment: This answers has the implicit assumption that there are "mixed doubles teams" which train together and actually care a lot about winning - but that's not really the case: mixed doubles is played only at the Grand Slams, with pairs often formed in the couple of days before the tournament for a bit of fun. As such, it _is_ treated a lot differently from the "regular" competitions.